# How to use dynamic condition with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I have a table `houseAttribute`

```
----------------------------
- houseId - AttrId - Value -
----------------------------
- 1       - 1      - 5     -
- 1       - 2      - 6     -
- 2       - 1      - 3     -
- 3       - 2      - 7     -
----------------------------
```

I want select all house when have the condition ex. `[{attrId: 1, value: 5 }, {attrId: 2, value: 7 }]`

**OutPut**

```
----------------------------
- houseId - AttrId - Value -
----------------------------
- 1       - 1      - 5     -
- 3       - 2      - 7     -
----------------------------
```

I don't want write a condition like that

```
SELECT         HouseId, Value, Attribute
FROM            houseAttribute
where Attribute = 1 and Value = 5 AND
      Attribute = 2 and Value = 7
      .......
      .......
```

> Because I want a dynamic condition

Comment: and dynamic means?

Comment: Meaning undefined my vars, e.g. @ var1, @ var2, @ var3, @varN ….

Comment: [This article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) discusses your options, thoroughly discussing the performance implications.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR` for the correct logic:

```
SELECT HouseId, Value, Attribute
FROM houseAttribute
WHERE (Attribute = 1 and Value = 5) OR
      (Attribute = 2 and Value = 7);
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamic condition".  But you can use parameters:

```
SELECT HouseId, Value, Attribute
FROM houseAttribute
WHERE (Attribute = @attr_1 and Value = @val_1) OR
      (Attribute = @attr_2 and Value = @val_2);
```

Comment: i can not use your answer because undefined my var, e.g. @ var1, @ var2, @ var3, @varN ....

Answer (score 1):

You can use execute string

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql   
      N'SELECT         HouseId, Value, Attribute
FROM            houseAttribute
where ( Attribute = @a and Value = @b) OR( Attribute = @c and Value = @d) ',  
      N'@a INT',  N'@b INT',  N'@c INT',  N'@d INT',  
      @a= 1,  @b= 5,@c= 2,@d= 7;
```

Comment: Yes, I know your way but try anther way